# Codeigniter 3 user authenticate with base controller and database check

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, authentication

I have this on my pages controller.

```
protected $auth = array();

function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
$this->auth['result'] = $this->is_logged_in();
}
```

and this is my core/base controller located at core folder.

```
public function is_logged_in(){
$session = $this->session->userdata();
if(isset($session['logged_in'])){
    return $session;
}else{ return FALSE; }
}
```

Is the above codes enough? or am i missing something to do a legitimate authentication?(my first time trying to attempt a user authentication)

Also, would it be okay, if for example.

I added a column '`isLoggedin`' on my accounts table.

```
int(1),NULL.
```

and whenever my login function is called and someone successfully logs in, i will also add a value to insert as '`isLoggedin`' to 1. `1=true, 2=false`.

So for example in my pages controller, since everytime it loads, it runs the `is_logged_in()` function in my base controller and would return the session data from there.

I would compare the returned session data from my base controller to the one in my accounts table with the '`isLoggedin`' col set to 1.

OR

since the `$auth` data would return an `'id'` then i would check the `'id'` from `$auth` to any `'id'` on the database where `'isLoggedin == 1'`. If it matches with the 'id' from `$auth`.

```
$this->db->get_where('accounts', array('id' => $auth['id'], 'isLoggedin' => 1));
```

Comment: Having `isLoggedin` column is showing that you are totally in a wrong direction. This is an example for how I extend the base controller of CI: https://github.com/DragonComputer/telve.net/blob/master/application/core/MY_Controller.php

Comment: No longer have is_logged_in column on my database table. Instead i am just comparing the session data with the data on my database if it matches.

Though my initial idea of adding an isloggedin was for that purpose to check if the data matches in my database and if the matched data's is_logged_in = true. 
(the default is false/0 and whenever a login occurs the corresponding is_logged_in would be changed to true).